# Need to select appropriate collection class for the specific task

Tags: c#, .net

I'm looking for a design solution for the following problem:

I have a large set of items which I need to compare with other set of items to find intersection and exception sets. In the same time inner state of this items might change on the run, though this state does not affect item's identity.

I would use something like `HashSet<T>` to run `Except` and `Intersect` operations and to add items quickly, but I cannot update state of the item as there is no operation to get element from the set.

I would use `Dictionary<string, T>` to add items quickly and have quick access to them to change their state, but there are no set comparison operations provided for `IDictionary`.

How would you solve the problem, keeping performance consideration in mind?

Comment: Does the inner state of an item affect its hashing or equality with other items? If so, hash set type collections (Dictionaries/HashSet) are not appropriate unless you remove and re-add modified items.

Comment: Like I said it does not affect identity, so it does not affect hashing or equality too. Item's identity is fixed once the item is added to collection

Comment: So at what point do you update an item's state? What's the selection criteria?

Comment: You could have both a HashSet and a Dictionary.  Any time a new item is added, add it to both of them.

Comment: @spender, item being added to collection, might change its state at any point of time later on, so that knowing its Id I need to find it in collection by Id, and change its state, lets say increment Count property which does not define item's identity

Comment: @Patrick Y, yes, I can keep both, but I would prefer to avoid it as collections are huge even for keeping just Ids in memory, plus I do not want to deal with data inconsistency issues (as data are duplicated, need to make sure both collections are updated properly in time). Though I think it might be "so-so" solution if I do not find anything better

Comment: Is there a one-to-one relationship between the strings you'd use with the dictionary? I.e. every T would always have the same string as well as each string having the same (or equivalent) T? If so, not only could you use the extension methods `Except`, `Intersect` from `System.Linq.Enumerable` on the dictionary, but it's also trivial to optimise them further for that case.

Comment: @Jon Hanna, right, it is one-to-one relationship. My concern is that this extension methods would work slow for IEnumerable opposing to ISet, would not they?

Comment: Hence my mentioning optimising further for that case. Answer coming...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I noted in the comment above, the fact that all values will have the same key means that all `IDictionary<string, T>` will have the same `KeyValuePair<string, T>` and so you could just use the extension methods.

More so, one could also take advantage of the fac that the guarantee of a fixed key per item means that you could do set operations based on keys alone. This allows you to quickly duplicate the `ISet<T>` methods with the following:

```
//Null-checks omitted for brevity:
public static class DictionaryAsSet
{
  //Note that some, but not all, of these methods allow one to use two dictionaries
  //with different types of value, as long as they've the same type of key.
  //They also assume that the same `IEqualityComparer<TKey>` is used, and will be
  //weird in results otherwise.
  public static void ExceptWithByKey<TKey, TValue1, TValue2>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue1> dictionary, IDictionary<TKey, TValue2> other)
  {
    if(dictionary.Count != 0)
    {
      if(dictionary == (object)other)
        dictionary.Clear();
      else
        foreach(TKey key in other.Keys)
          dictionary.Remove(key);
    }
  }
  public static void IntersectWithByKey<TKey, TValue1, TValue2>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue1> dictionary, IDictionary<TKey, TValue2> other)
  {
    if(dictionary.Count != 0 && dictionary != (object)other )
    {
      List<TKey> toRemove = new List<TKey>();
      foreach(TKey key in other.Keys)
        if(!dictionary.ContainsKey(key))
          toRemove.Add(key);
      if(toRemove.Count == dictionary.Count)
        dictionary.Clear();
      else
        foreach(TKey key in toRemove)
          dictionary.Remove(key);
    }
  }
  public static bool IsSubsetOfByKey<TKey, TValue1, TValue2>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue1> dictionary, IDictionary<TKey, TValue2> other)
  {
    if(dictionary.Count == 0 || dictionary == (object)other)
      return true;
    if(dictionary.Count > other.Count)
      return false;
    foreach(TKey key in dictionary.Keys)
      if(!other.ContainsKey(key))
        return false;
    return true;
  }
  public static bool IsProperSubsetOfByKey<TKey, TValue1, TValue2>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue1> dictionary, IDictionary<TKey, TValue2> other)
  {
    return dictionary.Count < other.Count && dictionary.IsSubsetOfByKey(other);
  }
  public static bool IsSupersetOfByKey<TKey, TValue1, TValue2>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue1> dictionary, IDictionary<TKey, TValue2> other)
  {
    return other.IsSubsetOfByKey(dictionary);
  }
  public static bool IsProperSupersetOfByKey<TKey, TValue1, TValue2>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue1> dictionary, IDictionary<TKey, TValue2> other)
  {
    return other.IsProperSubsetOfByKey(dictionary);
  }
  public static bool OverlapsByKey<TKey, TValue1, TValue2>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue1> dictionary, IDictionary<TKey, TValue2> other)
  {
    if(dictionary.Count == 0 || other.Count == 0)
      return true;
    if(dictionary == (object)other)
      return true;
    foreach(TKey key in dictionary.Keys)
      if(other.ContainsKey(key))
        return true;
    return false;
  }
  public static bool SetEqualsByKey<TKey, TValue1, TValue2>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue1> dictionary, IDictionary<TKey, TValue2> other)
  {
    if(dictionary == (object)other)
      return true;
    if(dictionary.Count != other.Count)
      return false;
    foreach(TKey key in dictionary.Keys)
      if(!other.ContainsKey(key))
        return false;
    return true;
  }
  public static void SymmetricExceptWithByKey<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, IDictionary<TKey, TValue> other)
  {
    if(dictionary.Count == 0)
      dictionary.UnionWithByKey(other);
    else if(dictionary == other)
      dictionary.Clear();
    else
    {
      List<TKey> toRemove = new List<TKey>();
      List<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> toAdd = new List<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>();
      foreach(var kvp in other)
        if(dictionary.ContainsKey(kvp.Key))
          toRemove.Add(kvp.Key);
        else
          toAdd.Add(kvp);
      foreach(TKey key in toRemove)
        dictionary.Remove(key);
      foreach(var kvp in toAdd)
        dictionary.Add(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
    }
  }
  public static void UnionWithByKey<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, IDictionary<TKey, TValue> other)
  {
    foreach(var kvp in other)
      if(!dictionary.ContainsKey(kvp.Key))
        dictionary.Add(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
  }
}
```

Most of these should be comparable in efficiency to `HashSet<T>` though there are just a few optimisations we can't do that `HashSet<T>` gets to do by having access to its own internals.

Alternatively, if you prefer the way the `System.Linq.Enumerable` extension methods work, you could create an optimised version of them for this particular scenario. E.g.:

```
public static class DictionaryAsSetEnumerable
{
  //we could also return IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue1>> if we wanted
  public static IEnumerable<TValue1> Except<TKey, TValue1, TValue2>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue1> dictionary, IDictionary<TKey, TValue2> other)
  {
    if(dictionary.Count != 0 && dictionary != (object)other)
    {
       foreach(var kvp in dictionary)
         if(!other.ContainsKey(kvp.Key))
           yield return kvp.Value;
    }
  }
  //And so on. The approach for each here should be clear from those above 
}
```

Comparing with the implementation of `Enumerable.Except()` should show that this is faster, being able to make some assumptions `Enumerable.Except` cannot.

A final approach is composing set objects. Here we create a class to represent each method. E.g.:

```
public static class DictionarySetExtensions
{
  public static IDictionary<TKey, TValue> ExceptByKey<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, IDictionary<TKey, TValue> other)
  {
    return new ExceptDictionary<TKey, TValue>(dictionary, other);
  }
  private class ExceptDictionary<TKey, TValue> : IDictionary<TKey, TValue>
  {
    private readonly IDictionary<TKey, TValue> _source;
    private readonly IDictionary<TKey, TValue> _exclude;
    public ExceptDictionary(IDictionary<TKey, TValue> source, IDictionary<TKey, TValue> exclude)
    {
      _source = source;
      _exclude = exclude;
    }
    public TValue this[TKey key]
    {
      get
      {
        if(_exclude.ContainsKey(key))
          throw new KeyNotFoundException();
        return _source[key];
      }
      //A non-readonly version is possible, but probably ill-advised. This sort of
      //approach creates surprises if you don't use immutable results.
      set { throw new InvalidOperationException("Read Only Dictionary"); }
    }
    ICollection<TKey> IDictionary<TKey, TValue>.Keys
    {
      get
      {
        //there are more efficient approaches by creating a wrapper
        //class on this again, but this shows the principle.
        return this.Select(kvp => kvp.Key).ToList();
      }
    }
    ICollection<TValue> IDictionary<TKey, TValue>.Values
    {
      get
      {
        return this.Select(kvp => kvp.Value).ToList();
      }
    }
    //Note that Count is O(n), not O(1) as usual with collections.
    public int Count
    {
      get
      {
        int tally = 0;
        using(var en = GetEnumerator())
          while(en.MoveNext())
            ++tally;
        return tally;
      }
    }
    bool ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.IsReadOnly
    {
      get { return true; }
    }
    public bool ContainsKey(TKey key)
    {
      return _source.ContainsKey(key) && !_exclude.ContainsKey(key);
    }
    void IDictionary<TKey, TValue>.Add(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
      throw new InvalidOperationException("Read only");
    }
    bool IDictionary<TKey, TValue>.Remove(TKey key)
    {
      throw new InvalidOperationException("Read only");
    }
    public bool TryGetValue(TKey key, out TValue value)
    {
      if(_exclude.ContainsKey(key))
      {
        value = default(TValue);
        return false;
      }
      return _source.TryGetValue(key, out value);
    }
    void ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.Add(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
    {
      throw new InvalidOperationException("Read only");
    }
    void ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.Clear()
    {
      throw new InvalidOperationException("Read only");
    }
    public bool Contains(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
    {
      TValue cmp;
      return TryGetValue(item.Key, out cmp) && Equals(cmp, item.Value);
    }
    public void CopyTo(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
      //Way lazy here for demonstration sake. This is the sort of use of ToList() I hate, but you'll get the idea.
      this.ToList().CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
    }
    bool ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.Remove(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
    {
      throw new InvalidOperationException("Read only");
    }
    public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> GetEnumerator()
    {
      foreach(var kvp in _source)
        if(!_exclude.ContainsKey(kvp.Key))
          yield return kvp;
    }
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
      return GetEnumerator();
    }
  }
}
```

With this approach calling `ExceptByKey` returns a new object that behaves as if it contained the set-operation exception. Calling `UnionByKey` would return an instance of a different class that took the same approach, and so on. Of course, you have to create a new class for each such method, but this can be quite fast if you start with an abstract base like:

```
internal abstract class ReadOnlyDictionaryBase<TKey, TValue> : IDictionary<TKey, TValue>
{
  public TValue this[TKey key]
  {
    get
    {
      TValue value;
      if(!TryGetValue(key, out value))
        throw new KeyNotFoundException();
      return value;
    }
  }
  TValue IDictionary<TKey, TValue>.this[TKey key]
  {
    get { return this[key]; }
    set { throw new InvalidOperationException("Read only"); }
  }
  public ICollection<TKey> Keys
  {
    get { return this.Select(kvp => kvp.Key).ToList(); }
  }
  public ICollection<TValue> Values
  {
    get { return this.Select(kvp => kvp.Value).ToList(); }
  }
  public int Count
  {
    get
    {
      int tally = 0;
      using(var en = GetEnumerator())
        while(en.MoveNext())
          ++tally;
      return tally;
    }
  }
  bool ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.IsReadOnly
  {
    get { return true; }
  }
  public bool ContainsKey(TKey key)
  {
    TValue unused;
    return TryGetValue(key, out unused);
  }
  void IDictionary<TKey, TValue>.Add(TKey key, TValue value)
  {
    throw new NotSupportedException("Read only");
  }
  bool IDictionary<TKey, TValue>.Remove(TKey key)
  {
    throw new NotSupportedException("Read only");
  }
  public abstract bool TryGetValue(TKey key, out TValue value);
  void ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.Add(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
  {
    throw new NotSupportedException("Read only");
  }
  void ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.Clear()
  {
    throw new NotSupportedException("Read only");
  }
  public bool Contains(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
  {
    TValue value;
    return TryGetValue(item.Key, out value) && Equals(value, item);
  }
  public void CopyTo(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>[] array, int arrayIndex)
  {
    this.ToList().CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
  }
  bool ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.Remove(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
  {
    throw new NotSupportedException("Read only");
  }
  public abstract IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> GetEnumerator();
  IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
  {
    return GetEnumerator();
  }
}
```

Then you need only implement `TryGetValue()` and `GetEnumerable()` to implement a class, e.g.:

```
internal class  UnionDictionary<TKey, TValue> : ReadOnlyDictionaryBase<TKey, TValue>
{
  private readonly IDictionary<TKey, TValue> _first;
  private readonly IDictionary<TKey, TValue> _second;
  public UnionDictionary(IDictionary<TKey, TValue> first, IDictionary<TKey, TValue> second)
  {
    _first = first;
    _second = second;
  }
  public override bool TryGetValue(TKey key, out TValue value)
  {
    return _first.TryGetValue(key, out value) || _second.TryGetValue(key, out value);
  }
  public override IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> GetEnumerator()
  {
    foreach(var kvp in _first)
      yield return kvp;
    foreach(var kvp in _second)
      if(!_first.ContainsKey(kvp.Key))
        yield return kvp;
  }
}
```

Though you might want to make some members virtual and then override them with optimisations, e.g. with the above `UnionDictionary` we could benefit from:

```
public override int Count
{
  get
  {
    int tally = _first.Count;//O(1) if _first has an O(1) Count
    foreach(var kvp in _second)
      if(!_first.ContainsKey(kvp.Key))
        ++tally;
    return tally;
  }
}
```

The interesting thing here, is that the relative efficiencies of different tasks are completely different to the other approaches: The result is returned in O(1) time instead of O(n) or O(n + m) as per most of the other cases. Most calls into the object are also O(1) albeit still slower than calls into the original dictionaries would be, while `Count` has gone from being O(1) to O(n).

Also notable, is that these objects become less efficient the more source objects there are in them. Hence if we were to take a few small dictionaries and do lots of set-based operations on it, this approach would soon end up being much slower, as calls on the methods end up having more and more work to do. On the other hand, if we have massive dictionaries and do just a few set operations on them, then this approach can be much much faster, because we have very little in the way of copying, allocation, and iterating through sequences.

There is a further interesting advantage and interesting disadvantage to this approach.

The interesting advantage, is that this can offer great thread-safety. Since all of these operations produce immutable objects from arguments that they don't mutate either, you can have hundreds of threads working on shared dictionaries without any risk of mutation. Of course, someone mutating the source `Dictionary` will ruin things for all of those threads, but that can be avoided by simply not mutating them once created, or else by enforcing it:

```
public ExceptDictionary(IDictionary<TKey, TValue> source, IDictionary<TKey, TValue> exclude, IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer)
{
  _source = source.IsReadOnly ? source : source.ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value, comparer);
   _exclude = exclude.IsReadOnly ? exclude : exclude.ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value, comparer);
}
```

Sadly this only works if we know what comparer we're using. It has the further advantage that if we know there can't be any mutation of the source dictionaries, then we can memoise the more expensive calls so e.g. `Count` need only be O(n) the first time, and can be O(1) on subsequent calls.

(Conversely, while not thread-safe the opposite can also be useful; one changes some source dictionaries according to changes in application state, and the objects representing set operations are automatically updated).

The interesting disadvantage is how bad this can be with garbage collection. This general approach is often really good when it comes to garbage collection because of the potential for reuse of the same collection in multiple places. This though is not an example of that, because we can have objects in memory that exist purely to indicate that a key does not have a matching value, or duplicated across the two sources of a union, etc. with lots of operations you could have gigs of memory to create a structure that only has a handful of elements semantically contained. You can get around this by periodically dumping the contents into a `Dictionary`, and allowing the waste to be collected. Just how often one should do this is a balance - too often misses the whole point of this approach, while too rarely leaves one with massive waste.

One approach is to add an internal-visible `Depth` field to `ReadOnlyDictionaryBase` which we set on construction:

```
public static IDictionary<TKey, TValue> UnionByKey<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> first, IDictionary<TKey, TValue> second)
{
  var firstRO = first as ReadOnlyDictionaryBase<TKey, TValue>;
  var secondRO = second as ReadOnlyDictionaryBase<TKey, TValue>;
  depth = (firstRO == null ? 1 : firstRO.Depth) + (secondRO == null ? 1 : secondRO.Depth);
  var result = new UnionDictionary<TKey, TValue>(first, second, depth);
  return depth > MAX_DEPTH ? result.DumpToDictionary() : result;
}
```

Comment: wow, good job. Thanks. Let me some time to study and test your approach

Comment: NP. You've a few different options there to pick between, so hopefully at least one suits your use-case.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a large set of items which I need to compare with other set of items to find intersection and exception sets. In the same time inner state of this items might change on the run, though this state does not affect item's identity.

While technically you can change an object which is a Key in a `Dictionary` or exists in a `HashSet`, and it will be fine as long as none of the changed internal data is used in your object's `GetHashCode` or `Equals` method, this seems like a really strange way to do things. I would discourage you from doing this, and suggest splitting your object up.

Why? I built some framework-type code a few years ago where object equality was based on *some* but not *all* of an object's fields (it was a similar thing to what you describe where some properties make up the ID, and others just make up extra data), and it's caused quite a few bugs since then as other developers are continuously surprised and confused by it. My learnings from this were that C# developers by and large seem to expect objects to have either:

- Reference equality only
- "Deep" equality based on all the fields.

Because it wasn't simply reference equality, people would change an "extra" field, and then wonder why their 2 objects were still equal even though the extra fields were different.

**A suggestion on how to split it up**

Make the key part into an immutable class or struct, and have a second class which contains your mutable data. You should then happily be able to put all your key parts into a `Dictionary`, and update the mutable data without causing problems (or confusion).

You'd have to write your own Except/Intersect methods, but that shouldn't be too hard.

As an example, instead of this:

```
public class Item {
    readonly int key1;
    readonly  string key2;

    string extra1;
    DateTime extra2;

    public override Equals(Object other) {
        var otherItem = other as Item;
        if(otherItem == null)
            return false;

        return key1 == other.key1 && key2 == other.key2
    } // and equivalent GetHashCode which only checks key1 and key2
}

var data = new HashSet<Item>(); ...
```

you could have something like this

```
public class ItemKey {
    readonly int key1;
    readonly string key2;

    // implement equals, gethashcode, etc
}

public class ItemData {
    string extra1;
    DateTime extra2;

    // don't implement equals, just rely on reference equality here
}

var data = new Dictionary<ItemKey, ItemData>() ...
```

You can then do hashset operations like `Intersect` based on the keys alone, and just bring the `ItemData` along when you do it.

Comment: Sorry, I do not get your idea. Could you please add some examples. Let's say I have class with `string Id` which is identity and `int Count` which is state to be updated

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest use HashSet.

```
Except() and Intersect() with other set. 
Add() for adding new element.
ToList() (extension method) for accessing each elements in the set.
```

Comment: ToList() would not let me access items quickly by Id, but by index which I do not need. LINQ statements on other hand, go through all items until requested item is found which is slow.